# WebSphere deployment without down time

Tags: deployment, websphere

Does WebSphere have a similar feature like side by side deployment/versioning as in Weblogic. I need to deploy my application on WebSphere with minimal downtime/restarting the Clusters. Any pointers on this will be helpful

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656214/how-can-i-do-zero-down-time-deployment-on-cluster-environment

Answer (score 0):

All depends on your version and specific requirements. See some options below.

You must have WAS 8.5.5 or later. Then you could use Application edition management see [Deploying and managing application editions with Intelligent Management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twve_appedtop.html)

For earlier versions you could use [rollout update](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_app_upgrade_console.html). Rollout Update sequentially updates the configuration on the nodes that contain cluster members.

Or manual process described here - [Maintain continuous availability while updating WebSphere Application Server enterprise applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0412_vansickel/0412_vansickel.html)